# Powershell - pipe get-mailbox results to a datatable

Tags: powershell, datatables

I'm trying to pipe the Get-Mailbox command into a datatable so I can then pull results from it depending on the data requested by the user.

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName blabla@blabla.com
#Define data table and columns
$v_Rooms = New-Object System.Data.Datatable 'VehicleDataTable'
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn VehicleName,([string]); $v_Rooms.Columns.Add($newcol)
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn VehicleType,([string]); $v_Rooms.Columns.Add($newcol)
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn VehicleLocation,([string]); $v_Rooms.Columns.Add($newcol)


#Add data
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter "(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'RoomMailbox') -and (CustomAttribute1 -eq 'Vehicle')" | select name,customattribute2, Office
$mailboxes | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $v_Rooms.NewRow()
    $row.VehicleName= ($_.Name)
    $row.VehicleType= ($_.CustomAttribute2)
    $row.VehicleLocation= ($_.Office)
}
$v_Rooms
```

This is my current code and $v_Rooms currently returns a blank table but the Get-Mailbox command returns exactly what I need it to. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but how can I get the data from the Get-Mailbox command to be properly added to the DataTable I've created?

This is the mailbox commands results:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I managed to fix my own problem. I was missing a few lines of code. See below for the working code. I created a function to add the data to the table so it can be looped easily if new Vehicle rooms are added

```
#Define data table and columns
$v_Rooms = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
$newcol0 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn ID,([int])
$newcol1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn VehicleName,([string])
$newcol2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn VehicleType,([string])
$newcol3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn VehicleLocation,([string])
$v_Rooms.Columns.Add($newcol0)
$v_Rooms.Columns.Add($newcol1)
$v_Rooms.Columns.Add($newcol2)
$v_Rooms.Columns.Add($newcol3)


#Create Add-Data function
function Add-Data {
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter "(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'RoomMailbox') -and (CustomAttribute1 -eq 'Vehicle')" | select name,customattribute2, Office
$count = 0
$mailboxes | ForEach-Object {
    
    $row = $v_Rooms.NewRow()
    $row.VehicleName= ($_.Name)
    $row.VehicleType= ($_.CustomAttribute2)
    $row.VehicleLocation= ($_.Office)
    $row.ID= ($count)
    $count++
    $v_Rooms.Rows.Add($row)
    
}
}
Add-Data
$v_Rooms
```